# Providing access to run specific pipelines in a data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there any way via which we can allow users to execute some specific pipelines in ADF rather than giving access on entire ADF?
Is creating a separate ADF the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom role (which is not assignble scope) to give access on a specific pipeline via powershell.

```
“assignableScopes”: [
        “/subscriptions/<<SubscriptionID>>/resourceGroups/<<RGName>>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<<ADFName>>/pipelines/<<PipelineName>>”
    ],
    “permissions”: [
        {
            “actions”: [
                “Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines/createrun/action”
            ],
            “notActions”: [],
            “dataActions”: [],
            “notDataActions”: []
        }
    ]
```

For details my blog for reference: https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/07/26/security-access-to-trigger-a-specific-pipeline-in-azure-data-factory/

No need to create a new ADF